# How do I fix weird graphical glitches and Wine problems?

Tags: unity, graphics, wine, lxde

Using Ubuntu 14.04 with LXDE is installed.

However, I encounter really weird things when connecting to the server via VNC. When first connecting, I usually see this (and it's alright!):

[image: login screen]

But after successfully logging in to LXDE (btw, Unity and Gnome do the same weird glitching), I am presented with this abomination:

[image: grey low res background]

This is quite strange. My aim was, to run a Windows-based app over wine, since the old API I was using for my app is pretty old and before completely abandoning it, I just wanted to play around. Trying to install a VM resulted in more insanity probably able to be source for some creepypasta:

[image: unreadable dialogs]

Yep, even worse. I decided to try it over wine, which yields the following error:

[image: CLI]

I've pretty much run into a concrete wall now. Would anybody be kind enough to help a newcomer and point him in the right direction? Installed in that machine is a Cirrus Logic VGA adapter, if that helps at all.

Edit: More hardware data, as requested. (Used `sudo lshw -html > ~/hardware_info.html && firefox ~/hardware_info.html`)

```
**CPU**  
cpu: 0  
description: CPU  
product: QEMU Virtual CPU version 1.0  
vendor: Intel Corp.  
physical id: 401  
bus info: cpu@0  
slot: CPU 1  
size: 2GHz  
capacity: 2GHz  
width: 64 bits  
capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 syscall nx x86-64 rep_good nopl pni vmx cx16 popcnt hypervisor lahf_lm  
(Stuff above x4 for 4 Cores)

**RAM**  
id:   
bank  
description:    DIMM RAM  
physical id:    0  
slot:   DIMM 0  
size:   16GiB  
width:  64 bits  

**GPU**  
id: display  
description:    VGA compatible controller  
product:    GD 5446  
vendor: Cirrus Logic  
physical id:    2  
bus info:     
pci@0000:00:02.0  
version:    00  
width:  32 bits  
clock:  33MHz  
capabilities:   vga_controller  
configuration:      
latency =   0  
resources:    
memory  :   fc000000-fdffffff  
memory  :   febf0000-febf0fff   
memory  :   febd0000-febdffff
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) Could you please give us a bit more information like: What graphics hardware do you have?  Please [edit] your question and add this information...

Comment: please add answers in the answer area when you are able, and use the green check mark instead of solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LXDE was unable to install/assign the correct kernel drivers for the Cirrus VGA-adapter. The command

```
lspci -nnk | grep "VGA\|'Kern'\|3D\|Display" -A2
```

was used to determine the status of the graphics driver/kernel loaded and it replied the wrong result, stating that there was no valid kernel loaded

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller  
[0300]: Cirrus Logic GD 5446 [1013:00b8]
Subsystem: Red Hat, Inc QEMU Virtual Machine [1af4:1100]
```

Stopping the GUI via

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

and creating a custom xorg.conf via

```
X -configure
```

followed by

```
sudo nano /home/[username]/xorg.conf.new
```

was the correct solution. There change the device-part from:

```
Section "Device"
Identifier "default"
Driver "default"
BusID "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```

to

```
Section "Device"
Identifier "Cirrus Logic GD 5446"
Driver "vesa"
BusID "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```

Afterwards save it as **xorg.conf** and use

```
sudo mv /home/[username]/xorg.conf /etc/X11/
```

When you did this, restart your machine (sudo reboot) and everything should work fine.